# Samsung Galaxy A20 Viewport size

Tags: media-queries, viewport, samsung-mobile, viewport-units, mpmediaquery

I have to write a custom media query in portrait and landscape for **Samsung A20** and I can't find the **viewport**. Does anyone know this? (**not** for A20s or A20e).

Thanks

Comment: Asking the size of a particular piece of hardware is almost certainly "off topic" (verboten) on this site, but you can just find the viewport size directly...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the min and max width according to your requirement here

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 414px) and (orientation : portrait) {
                    //Put your CSS here for 200px to 414px width devices (cover all mobile portrait width //        
              }
        
        
 @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation:landscape) {
                    //Put your CSS here for 500px to 7674px width devices (cover all mobile landscape width //        
              }
```

Comment: thaks but I'm searching for the specific viewport not the range. I've to write a media query only for Samsung A20 and I've not the device.

Comment: I think the viewport should be 360px portrait and 640px landscape

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the current device viewport size:

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in short, if you will target every single mobile device out there, you would be nearly mad. So, my suggestion as a Front-End Developer is that you should always go for main break points and never forget to start from "max-width" in media query.... Max width will help you to target from 0 to 396px or 396px to 768px. But min-width will allow from 396px to 0.
So max-width is best option
and
Go for main break points for mobile devices

Comment: Thanks for reply and for suggestion :) . Actually I'm searching for the specific mq because is a project request. Normally I don't write a mq for every single device. I kow that use the range is the best way to approach a mq but in this specific situation it's not the solution.

Comment: Well, Elena maybe I can sort out your MQ problem. But can you please discuss your problem in details with me?
I have recently worked on my own Portfolio site and implemented same strategy as you saying. But after that  my portfolio site project, I learnt from my teacher that we should not target every single breaking point but general BPs(breakpoints).

Comment: Also, I would suggest you to always target one MQ and style it and make it responsive with some space to breathe if width increase or decrease.
It means that if you are targeting 396px max width, then make some room (in container class) to breathe if width decrease from 396px towards 330px or 320px. Most of the projects can be done with this strategy. It lets us to do smart work instead of hard work of targeting every single BP.
Still have any doubts in your mind? I would be happy to solve your problem. Maybe you can contact me on my Facebook or WhatsApp. Just Ping me and I will share my WA.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries for A20 portrait:
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 694px)

*(I'm not absolutely sure about WebKit but you can try 2.2)*

and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2.2)